# How to get posts of followed users

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4, feed

I'm trying to make news feed page, but in this page I need to output `articles` ordered by date and also they must belong to the user, which authed user follows. I tried a few things and than realised that I have the wrong logic. So in `user model` I have:

```
function followers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'followers', 'user_id', 'follower_id');
}

function follows()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'followers', 'follower_id', 'user_id');
}

function articles(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Article');
}
```

and than in `article` I have the relationships:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

I don't know if I can simplly get all articles and than output the ones the user follows. I'm kind of confused.

here is the code I use in controller:

```
 $followinguserarticle = Article::whereHas('user.follows', function($q) {
            $q->where('id', auth()->id());
        })
            ->latest()
            ->get();
```

And than I try to loop through them with:

```
@foreach($followinguserarticle as $followinguserarticles)
    <a>followinguserarticles->title</a>
@endforeach
```

Comment: try to fetch data from database and see if it works as expected or not

Comment: whoow I guess I have a bigger problem now, I couldnt even return and loop through articles at all

Comment: it says invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: @Sohel0415 do you know what might be causing this?

Comment: show your full controller code with return statement

Comment: I figured it out

Comment: that's wonderful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution I found is like this:

```
//get list of follower ids
$follows = Auth::user()->follows->pluck('id');

//get articles of those that user follows
$articles = Article::whereIn('user_id',$follows)
                      ->with('user')
                      ->latest()
                      ->limit(10)
                      ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence):

```
Article::whereHas('user.followers', function($q) {
    $q->where('id', auth()->id());
})
->latest()
->get();
```

Comment: @Nikonah yeah, I was a bit confused by the relationships. I've first posted `follows` and then changed it to `followers`. Please try both.

Comment: I assume I'm supposed to give a variable and assigne the query to it, and than I need to loop through it with foreach in the view right? If that is the case. it throws error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: @Nikonah it shouldn't give you the error even if no articles were found. Please show the code you're using.

Comment: @Nikonah the code is correct. Make sure you're passing `$followinguserarticle` from the controller to the view you've shown. If you do this, please show results of `{{ dd($followinguserarticle) }}`

Comment: To clearify my question, I want to show articles made by followed users. that is all, and I just want to order them by time and output 10 of them

Comment: @Nikonah yes, the query will do exactly this except limiting results to 10 (add `->take(10)` to the query for this). But I'm not sure about the relationship, so please try to use both.

Comment: It gives me the error  Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous. plus the ide says 'whereHas' should not be called statically., But I don't think that is a problem.

Comment: Can you please clearify what you are trying to do in Article::whereHas('user.followers', function($q) and   $q->where('id', auth()->id()); cuz I feel like you are making mistakes

Comment: @Nikonah I'm pretty sure the query is ok and the only problem here is ambiguous ID. You can read the docs on `whereHas()` if you don't know how it works. The other errors you got are not related to the query at all.

Comment: Yeah this is the conclusion I came too. I'm looking for other mistakes I might have done

Comment: I made it kinda work with $q->where('user.id', auth()->id()); but it basically gives me all the articles made buy the authed user

Answer (score 1):

You can *eager load* relationship on **authed** user instance

```
$authed = Auth::user();

$authed ->load('follows.articles');
```

Now you have articles of users whom users follows

```
foreach($authed->follows as $follow){
   foreach($follow->articles as $article){

       //Now you have access to each article
   }
}
```

Comment: When you do `User::find(Auth::id())` you're executing an additional query to load authenticated user instance which is already loaded by Laravel. Also, the articles will not be sorted by date as OP wants, they will be grouped by users and not sorted.

Comment: Still not sorted. Also, OP wants to limit results by 10.